# convenient sha-ing in python

Tags: python, caching, sha256

I frequently have a class object (e.g., a message of protocol type, or a a specific number object of a group), and I just want to pull the sha256 or sha512 out of it (should not matter). I also very often have a collection of like four objects L,K,v,m and again I want the hash of [L,K,v,m]. Here, the notation [] is language-agnostic.

Question: How do I do that?

It is not even about doing it easily and quickly, but really on practically doing it at all when I have a class that is like 1000 lines of code. I cannot seriously write another thousand lines of code just to update a sha on every property of every potential list item in each list and make a recursive mess that in the end is filled with difficult-to-spot errors. I also do not want to get involved with attr.s and dataclass. I just want to get the hash of a class object. It is an actual practical serious technical challenge.

Is there some boilerplate code that you use to iterate through all properties of all attributes and search for a function to call that updates a hashlib object and in the end generate the digest?

How can it practically be done?

Comment: It's a little hard to know how to answer this question in the abstract. If you have a class that's 1000 of lines of code and the attributes are also collections, like lists of further objects, then of course it will be complicated to describe what parts of the class make it unique. That's not really a hashing problem...you would have the same challenge defining equality between instances. Maybe it's an indication that some refactoring is called for?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I want to hash "whatever data is necessary to entirely reproduce this class object from a print-out sheet". Sure, in other languages like C++ I could readily see what is a pointer and define my class like so that a hash of the object's memory is just what I need.

This is the way I would do it at the moment. But I really think it is ugly.

```
def get_hash(obj,sha):  # <-- bad coding: once as standalone and once as member
    if type(obj)==list : 
        for obji in obj          : sha = get_hash(obji,sha)
    elif type(obj)==int          : sha.update(bytes(obj))
    elif type(obj)==str          : sha.update(obj.encode("utf-8"))
    elif type(obj)==bytes        : sha.update(obj)
    elif hasattr(obj,"get_hash") : sha = obj.get_hash(sha)
    else                         : print(f"unhashed obj {type(obj)}")
    return sha

class Value:
    def __init__(self,VG):
        if VG==None : self.x=0   ; self.q=3
        else        : self.x=VG.x; self.q=VG.q
    def get_hash(self,sha):
        sha.update(bytes(self.x))   # <-- tedious and error-prone
        sha.update(bytes(self.q))
        return sha

a = Value()
b = Value(a)
b.x = 5

digest = get_hash([a,b,"foo",76432],hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()  # <-- overkill
```

Is there a cleaner way?